# Getting CException error

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm new to Yii and I'm following the screencasts tutorial of Yii. I did everything on the video but I'm getting an error

"Property "Message.content" is not defined."

```
$this->message = $message->content;
```

Here's my GreetingController.php

```
class GreetingController extends Controller
{

    public $message = '';

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $message = Message::model()->findByPk(3);
        $this->message = $message->content;
        $this->render('index', array('content'=>$this->message));
    }
```

What must be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wont be a field called `content` in your table Message.

Comment: There is id(3) = This is a test message